# Python Command Line Option Parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, getopt

I've a Python script and run it from command line with possible arguments.
After some arguments should add value.

For example:

```
[ab:c]
```

I am using getopt.getopt() Python function to get arguments and values.
I know if after an argument is colon means need to add value to the related argument. In this case: 'b'

How can I handle if user add arg. '-b' but missed to add value for -b but add the 3rd oprtion to command:

```
python3 mypythoncmd -a -b -c
```

If I am using getopt.getopt() function result is:

```
[('-a',''),('-b','-c')]
```

...but this wrong because '-c' is an another argument.

Is possible to handle it somehow? Missing value from arg throw and error?

Thanks

Comment: Try argparse library it is designed for parsing command line arguments in s POSIX way. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Hmm reading your question more closely, it is not unreasonable for the argument parser (regardless of what library you use) to take -c as the value for the -b parameter. in fact try it with existing command line arguments tool and they will make that same mistake.. Which is not a mistake, -b <val> should always interpret the value of the -b parameter to be "-c" when passed in like this. -b -c or you could not have -b -c -c where you want -b to take value "-c" and then have argument -c.. You cannot protect for syntax errors, you just flag them.. the user messed up let them fix it, do NOT do it.

Comment: Thanks your comments. I've tried argparse but at first getopt was more useful. So...probably I'll try it again or I stay with current solution and follow what Rob wrote.

Comment: that is fine, does it also provide the --help output? aka the usage text? In either case your tool is documented, tell them that "-c" is not a valid value for -b or just run with "-c" value for -b, you cannot fix their errors for them. again if it is not a valid value tell them if it is not, then you cannot guess what they were trying to do..